# Radio Buttons not generating an action after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple help page for my app. In it, you'll get some basic documentation on how to navigate and use the site. For each talking point, I am adding a simple questionnaire ("was this helpful?") where the user clicks on the radio buttons (yes or no) and an action generates based on their selection. I was able to successfully add one to the first talking point (see snippet), but when I tried adding it to others, it won't work as when I select "no" the textarea will not appear, nor will the user get a response if they select "yes" (see snippet). I gave the second one it's own ID's and it still will not generate an action.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```html
<div>
  <form id="myForm">
    <h4> This is the first one I was able to implement.</h4>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Yes</label>
       </div>
       <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">No</label>
        </div>
              <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>
    <div id="result" style="display:none"></div>
                            
  <div>
    <form id="myForm">
      <h4> This one does not work</h4>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample3" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">Yes</label>
        </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample4" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample3">No</label>
     </div>
     <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
     </form>
    </div>
   <div id="result" style="display:none"></div>
             
             
             <script>

let button = document.querySelector("input.button");

button.addEventListener("click", question1);


function question1() {
  var selection = document.querySelector("input[name='groupOfDefaultRadios']:checked");
        var result = document.getElementById("result");
   if (selection.value == 'yes') {
            result.innerHTML = "We're glad you found this helpful.";
        result.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    var output = "";
    output += "We're sorry! Please tell us how we can better serve you.<br />";
    output += "<textarea style='width: 500px; height 200px;'></textarea><br />";
       output += "<button>Submit</button>";
        result.innerHTML = output;
        result.style.display = "block";

      }
    }
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The document.querySelector(); function only returns the first element match, hence the event listener is only attached to the first button. Try the following code:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input.button");

buttons.forEach(function (button){
  button.addEventListener("click", question1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your forms had the same `id` and you were assigning an `eventListener` to only the first button element that is found on the page. As opposed to `.querySelector()`, `.querySelectorAll()` finds all the elements on the page that fit the query.

Also since the `input buttons` are completely the same (`id`, `class`, etc.) I used a different approach to obtain the wanted `radio buttons`... By finding out the `parent` of the clicked `button` we can find the `radio buttons` within that `parent`.

---

**Edit:** OP asked if response and textarea can appear for each form separately.

First change is to eliminate more than one element having the same `id` on the page (both result divs have the same `id`). If really necessary for both to have the same identifier then having the same `class` would make sense, not `id`. For the purpose of this example we will add a different `id` to each result `div` and have the `id` correlate to the `id` of its `form` (e.g. `form` id is `myForm1` while it's respective result `div` could have an `id` like `myForm1Result`).

---

Try it out below:

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll("input.button");

button.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", question1);
});

function question1() {
  let parent = this.parentElement;
  let parentId = parent.id;
  let resultDivId = parent.id + "Result";
  let radioBtns = parent.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  let yesIsChecked = false;
  
  // find out which one is checked
  for(let i=0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    let radio = radioBtns[i];
    if(radio.value == "yes" && radio.checked) {
      yesIsChecked = true;
    }
  }
  
  let result = document.getElementById(resultDivId);
  if (yesIsChecked) {
    result.innerHTML = "We're glad you found this helpful.";
    result.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    let output = "";
    output += "We're sorry! Please tell us how we can better serve you.<br />";
    output += "<textarea style='width: 500px; height 200px;'></textarea><br />";
    output += "<button>Submit</button>";
    result.innerHTML = output;
    result.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="myForm1">
    <h4> This is the first one I was able to implement.</h4>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">No</label>
    </div>
    <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="myForm1Result" style="display:none"></div>

<div>
  <form id="myForm2">
    <h4> This one does not work</h4>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample3" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample4" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample3">No</label>
    </div>
    <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="myForm2Result" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: I see what you did there, but how can that text and textarea appear below?  I would like for each question to have it's own response and textarea.